# Errors when trying to start a new Rails app with Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, spree, thor

I am getting the following error when trying to install Spree Commerce (a clean install) into a new rails application.

Could not load generator "generators/spree/install/install_generator". Error: uninitialized constant Bundler::Thor::Base.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I have already checked the resources on the SpreeCommerce Documentation, Spree's Github, and similar issues that have come up and those solutions do not work for me.

Edit:  Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'spree', '3.0.1'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-    stable'
```

Here are the commands I have tried (all on clean new rails apps...all have the same resulting error as above):

1)  I've tried using the methods listed on Spree's github page:

```
$ gem install spree
$ rails _4.2.1_ new my_store
$ spree install my_store
```

2)  I've tried adding spree gem manually to a new apps gemfile, and then:

```
$ bundle install
$ rails g spree:install --sample=false --seed=false
```

3)  I've tried following the steps as outlined on the spreecommerce tutorial:

```
$ gem install spree_cmd
$ rails new mystore
$ spree install --auto-accept
```

Comment: Can you post your gemfile?

Comment: and how exactly are you trying to install? could you post the commands you're trying to run?

Comment: @huoxito I added all of the combinations of commands I've tried.  I've tried each set of commands on clean rails apps (all 4.2.2).  They are the same as outlined on spree's github's page, and spree's getting started tutorial page

Comment: Works ok for me.  What ruby version are you using? `ruby -v`  I am on `ruby 2.1.2p95`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Seems like it had something to do with RVM.

I fixed it by creating a new gemset (although based on the same version of Ruby I was currently using), and creating a new rails app with that specific gemset.

I then added spree to my gemfile, and ran the following commands:

```
$ bundle install
$ rails g spree:install --sample=false --seed=false
```